# How to fix the useEffect won't update unless refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
//real time database listner :
const getJobStatusSnapshot = ()=> {

    const que = query(jobsCollectionRef, where("auth_ID", "==", user.uid))
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(que, (querySnapshot) => {
    const temp = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // cities.push(doc.data());
        temp.push({...doc.data(), id:doc.id})
        // console.log({...doc.data(), id:doc.id})
        setJobDoc(temp)
    });
    
    

    })
    unsubscribe();

}

useEffect(()=>{
    getJobStatusSnapshot()
},[])
```

Sometime it doesn't retrieve the data. I tried to pass [jobDoc]. But it gives me the same results. And then suddenly returns bunch of errors. Also, I noticed that if I wanna retrieve the data first time, I have to comment out > unsubscribe()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set your `useEffect` dependencies to `[jobDoc]` it will be trigger on mount and on `jobDoc` value update which happen inside `setJobDoc(temp)`, so it will be infinite loop which give you a bunch of errors. So if you only provide that code, I think you should listen to `[user]` or `[user.uid]`. Everytime the `user` or `user.uid` change it will rerun the `getJobStatusSnapshot`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getJobStatusSnapshot()
},[user])
```

Comment: Thanks. But unless I commented out `unsubscribe()` and reload the page, it won't get the data from firebase. After it load up, then I get promise unhandled error

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `[]` as dependency in useEffect, that means it only will perform that action when loading the page.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html